# How to prevent Terminal.app from displaying a tab bar when there is only one tab open

Tags: terminal

The image below is the header that appears when I open Terminal.app.  As you can see, only one tab is open, but a tab bar still shows (just has one tab that says "bash").  How can I prevent the tab bar from showing unless there are >= 2 tabs?  It was working correctly until recently but I can't figure out what changed or how to fix.

[image]

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Click "View" / "Hide Tab Bar" and the tab bar will go away and come back only when there is more than one tab open.

Comment: I will not have access to the computer that had this problem until Friday, but if this works then I will accept.

Comment: I scrubbed all over the preferences panel looking for this...  never occurred to me to look for a top-level menu.

Comment: After upgrading macOS, this tab preference reset, so I scoured preferences and didn't find it... they really need to move this to preferences -> General (or put it in both places). It acts like a preference because if you change it, it affects other windows.

Comment: I'm not sure when I originally thumbs--upped this response, but I had to come back here to find it again when I apparently hit SHIFT-CMD-T without realizing it and started getting tab-headers on all my windows.

Answer (score 1):

For all it's worth, in iTerm2 to achieve the same:

1. To make a temporary change you need to choose `Window->Window Style->No Title Bar`.
2. To make a permanent change, this is part of the profile.
   `Preferences->Profiles->[Your Profile]->Window->Style == No Title Bar`(default is `Normal`)

Update: Appologies - misread the question and added an answer for iTerm2, which may still be useful to someone. Alternatively the answer can be removed.

Comment: The question seems to be about Terminal, not iTerm2.

Comment: Aaah, I see - I missed that, thanks. Indeed this answer is for iTerm2, which may still be useful to someone. It took me time to find it in settings to make the change stick.